# TeleBot Error code: 400 при создании привязанной к пользователю темы

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота на пайтоне в телеграм. Выдает ошибку 400 когда бот пытается создать привязанную тему в отдельной группе (Сам бот находится в этой группе, с админкой).
Эта проблема возникла именно при запуске на хостинге - на локальном сервере всё работало

Ниже предоставлен фрагмент скрипта бота, где создаётся тема и т.д

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True,
                 content_types=['text', 'photo', 'animation', 'voice', 'sticker', 'audio',
                                'document'])  # Главный обработчик
```

async def main_handler(message: types.Message):
global user_ids, user_topics, chat_id, banned

```
print(message.content_type)

if message.chat.type == 'private':  # Если личная переписка с ботом
    if message.from_user.id not in banned:  # Проверка не в списке забаненных ли пользователь
        if user_topics.get(message.from_user.id) != None:  # Если к пользователю привязана тема
            await bot.forward_message(chat_id,  # Сообщение отправляется в группу
                                      message.chat.id,  # Айди чата переписки
                                      message.id,  # Айди сообщения
                                      message_thread_id=user_topics[
                                          message.from_user.id])  # Айди темы равно теме извлечённой по этому айди юзера
        else:  # Если к пользователю не привязана тема
            topic = await bot.create_forum_topic(chat_id,  # Создание темы в группе
                                                 f'{message.from_user.full_name} @{message.from_user.username}')  # Название темы в формате "Имя @никнейм, пример - "Sobaka Zlaya @sobaka3laya", на случай если..
            # у кого-то нет имени или никнейма
            user_topics[message.from_user.id] = topic.message_thread_id  # Привязывание айди темы
            user_ids[topic.message_thread_id] = message.chat.id  # Привязывание айди личных сообщений к теме

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('❌ БАН ❌',
                                                  callback_data=f'ban_{message.from_user.id}_{topic.message_thread_id}'))  # Создание кнопки бана с коллбэком формата ban_айдиюзера_айдитемы
            await bot.send_message(chat_id,
                                   # Отправление сообщения о новом диалоге, по сути существует для прикрепления кнопки бана
                                   f'Сообщение от нового пользователя @{message.from_user.username} {message.from_user.full_name}',
                                   reply_markup=markup,
                                   message_thread_id=topic.message_thread_id)  # Прикрепление кнопки бана
            await bot.forward_message(chat_id,  # Сообщение отправляется в группу
                                      message.chat.id,  # Айди чата переписки
                                      message.id,  # Айди сообщения
                                      message_thread_id=user_topics[
                                          message.from_user.id])  # Айди темы равно теме извлечённой по этому айди юзера
    else:  # Если в списке забаненных
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id,  # Отправить сообщение о том, что пользователь забанен
                               '*ТЫ ЗАБАНЕН ШКИЛА*',  # Сообщение о бане ЖИРНЫМ текстом
                               parse_mode='MarkdownV2')  # Режим парсинга, чтобы *текст* работало
else:  # Если не личная переписка(обратная связь)
    match message.content_type:  # Проверка типа сообщения
        case 'text':  # Если текст
            await bot.send_message(user_ids[message.message_thread_id],  # Отправление в лс этого юзера
                                   message.text)  # Текст из сообщения
        case 'photo':  # Если картинка
            await bot.send_photo(user_ids[message.message_thread_id],  # Отправление в лс этого юзера
                                 message.photo,  # Картинка из сообщения
                                 message.caption)  # Подпись картинки
        case 'animation':  # Если гифка
            await bot.send_animation(user_ids[message.message_thread_id],  # Отправление в лс этого юзера
                                     message.animation.file_id,  # Гифка из сообщения
                                     caption=message.caption)  # Подпись гифки
        case 'voice':  # Если голосовуха
            await bot.send_voice(user_ids[message.message_thread_id],  # Отправление в лс этого юзера
                                 message.voice.file_id)  # Эта голосовуха
        case 'sticker':  # Если стикер
            await bot.send_sticker(user_ids[message.message_thread_id],  # Отправление в лс этого юзера
                                   message.sticker.file_id)  # Этот стикер
        case 'audio':  # Если аудио
            await bot.send_audio(user_ids[message.message_thread_id],  # Отправление в лс этого юзера
                                 message.audio.file_id,  # Аудио из сообщения
                                 message.caption)  # Подпись из сообщения
        case 'document':  # Документ?
            await bot.send_document(user_ids[message.message_thread_id],  # Отправление в лс этого юзера
                                    message.document.file_id,  # Документ из сообщения
                                    caption=message.caption)  # Подпись из сообщения
```